# Using multiple iter vars in the for loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I'm quite new to python and I've got the following piece of code:

```
def multiply(x,y):
    return x*y

sequence = [args.x, args.y] # args.x and args.y come from the command line
combinations = it.product(*sequence)

for argx,argy in combinations:
    print (multiply(argx,argy))
```

My problem is that I've got a few dozen parameters like argx and argy and I ought to mention them all in the for-loop so that then I could refer to them by their names but it wouldn't look nice. 
I don't quite get it what I should do to avoid listing them all in a raw.
I also want to refer to all my variables by their names, not by their indices.
I sense there must be some simple solution but I can't find it.
Also, my actual code doesn't have anything to do with the multiply function, the code above is just a model in a way of my actual code.

Comment: What is it.product()?

Comment: oh it stands for itertools.product(), the itertools module is imported as it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` iterable to iterate over two lists in parallel:

```
xx = [1,2,3,4]
yy = [10,20,30,40]
for x,y in zip(xx,yy):
   print x + y
```

resulting in:

```
11
22
33
44
```

See in Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip